# How to use function definitions to open, read, and close a file

Tags: c++, function, file

We are asked to open a text file that contains a sentence and go through all the letters and whitespace in the file and count how many of each ascii character there are.

When I had all my information in the main function it worked fine. I just can't figure out how to call them all successfully in the main. The output should look like:

```
15 words  
6 a   
3 d  
6 e  
3 g  
3 h  
3 i  
15 l  
6 o  
6 r  
3 s  
3 t  
3 w
```

I achieved this output when again everything was in the main function so now it's just a matter of getting it like this with my function definitions.

My Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
    
//prototypes
//int openFile();
void readFile(ifstream &in);
void closeFile(ifstream &in);
    
//definitions
int openFile()
{
    ifstream in;
    in.open("word_data.txt");
}

void readFile(ifstream &in)
{
    //store the frequency of the letters
    int letters[128];
    
    //declare variables
    char let;
    int wordCount = 0;
    
    //for loop to initialize all counts to zero
    for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
    {
        letters[i] = 0;
    }

    //get letters until we reach end of file
    //whitespace = wordCount++;
    let = in.get();
    while (let != EOF)
    {
        if (let == ' ')
            wordCount++;
        
        //change to lowercase
        let = tolower(let);
        
        letters[let]++;
        let = in.get();
    }
    
    //output
    //num words
    cout << wordCount + 1 << " words" << endl;
        
    //count how many of each letter there are & print to screen in alphabetical order
    for (char let = 'a'; let <= 'z'; let++)
    {
        if (letters[let] != 0)
        {
            cout << letters[let] << " "<< let <<endl;
        }
    }
}

void closeFile(ifstream &in)
{
    in.close();
}
    
int main()
{
    openFile();
    readFile(in);
    closeFile(in);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile. `in` in `main` is undeclared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your `openFile()` function.  It creates a *local* `ifstream` only, it does not open an `ifstream` that is accessible to the other functions.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
    
//prototypes
void openFile(ifstream &in);
void readFile(ifstream &in);
void closeFile(ifstream &in);
    
//definitions
void openFile(ifstream &in)
{
    in.open("word_data.txt");
}

void readFile(ifstream &in)
{
    //store the frequency of the letters
    int letters[128] = {};
    
    //declare variables
    char ch;
    int wordCount = 0;

    //get letters until we reach end of file
    while (in.get(ch))
    {
        if (ch == ' ')
            wordCount++;
        
        //change to lowercase
        ch = static_cast<char>(tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));
        
        letters[ch]++;
    }
    
    //output
    //num words
    cout << wordCount + 1 << " words" << endl;
        
    //count how many of each letter there are & print to screen in alphabetical order
    for (ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    {
        if (letters[ch] != 0)
        {
            cout << letters[ch] << " " << ch <<endl;
        }
    }
}

void closeFile(ifstream &in)
{
    in.close();
}
    
int main()
{
    ifstream in;
    openFile(in);
    readFile(in);
    closeFile(in);
    return 0;
}
```

With that said, you might consider using a `std::map` to track your frequencies, rather than using an `int[]` array.  And using `operator>>` to read whole words at a time:

```cpp
#include <map>
...

void readFile(ifstream &in)
{
    //store the frequency of the letters
    map<char, int> letters;
    
    //declare variables
    string word;
    int wordCount = 0;

    //get letters until we reach end of file
    while (in >> word)
    {
        ++wordCount;
        
        //for(size_t idx = 0; idx < word.size(); ++idx)
        //{
        //    char ch = word[idx];
        for(char ch : word)
        {
            //change to lowercase
            ch = static_cast<char>(tolower(static_cast<unsigned char>(ch)));
        
            if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z')
                letters[ch]++;
        }
    }

    //output
    //num words
    cout << wordCount << " words" << endl;
        
    //count how many of each letter there are & print to screen in alphabetical order
    //for (map<char, int>::iterator iter = letters.begin(); iter != letters.end(); ++iter)
    //{
    //    cout << iter->second << " " << iter->first << endl;
    //}
    for (auto &elem : letters)
    {
        cout << elem.second << " " << elem.first << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was super helpful thank you so much!